# Problem : an integral using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

Hello everyone I need help with the following problem :

$
$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{(1+x)(x^{2}+1)}dx
\end{align*}
using the Residue theorem. 
I think that I could consider the contour integral
\begin{align*}
\oint_{C}\frac{\ln(z)}{(1+x)(x^{2}+1)}dz,
\end{align*}
But I'm struggling ..

also  how can I define $\log(z)$ , thanks in advance

Could someone help me?

Comment: Follow [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_5_%E2%80%93_the_square_of_the_logarithm) approach.

Comment: Take a branch cut along the positive real axis and use a keyhole contour.